# On hover of div, div slides up to bottom 3rd of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 2 divs, one of which is hidden. Once you hover over the div the hidden div slides down and once removed slides back up

```js
$("#clickk").hover(function() {
  if ($("#monster").is(":hidden")) {
    $("#monster").slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    $("#monster").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
div#monster {
  background: #de9a44;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

#clickk {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #cc0001;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="monster"></div>
<div id="clickk"></div><br />
```

I am trying to get the div to slide up, but only to the bottom 3rd section of the div, and when not hovering slide back down

Comment: Question was not clear?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to accomplish here, but I took a shot at it.

You may want to look into [`$.animate(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) rather than `$.slideUp(...)`.

I modified your snippet to slide the click div up a certain amount when you hover over it.

```js
$("#clickk").hover(function() {
  if ($('#monster').hasClass("small")) {
    $('#monster').animate({"height": "60px"}, "medium").removeClass("small");
  } 
  else {
    $('#monster').animate({"height": "20px"}, "meduim").addClass("small");
  }
});
```

```css
div#monster {
  background: #de9a44;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

#clickk {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #cc0001;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="monster"></div>
<div id="clickk"></div><br />
```

Comment: Sorry, that was on the right lines. What i am trying to do is, i have an image inside a div. When i hover over this div, another div with text up animates up to around the middle mark

Comment: What i have posted in the picture, on hover goes from down --> up .. i want it to go from down --> up but not right at the top, around 50% of the height of the visible div